# Magento 2 - Change Input type of Size attribute cause problem not showing

Tags: magento2

I migrated product from 1.7 to 2.1.6 and the product with Size attribute show drop down correctly.

Now I want to change the Size attribute to "Text Swatch" in Admin panel (Product attribute)but then the the size option in front end disappear. Just show "Size:" with no options to choose.

Is it a problem with Magento 2 or do I need to modify something else to make the Text Swatch work?

Comment: do you change the attribute settings to text swatch in admin panel?

Comment: Yes. I change to "Text Swatch" and it cause the problem, customer cannot select the size. If I change back to "Dropdown" it show dropdown correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you change the attribute settings in admin panel.

```
Dashboard -> Stores -> Attributes -> Product ->Size -> Catalog Input Type for Store Owner -> Text Swatch
```

Do this commands after change the settings.

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

sudo chmod 777 -R var/ pub/media pub/static vendor/
```

Comment: I change to "Text Swatch" and it cause the problem, customer cannot select the size. If I change back to "Dropdown" the size show dropdown correctly. So I wondering is there any problem or extra config for "Text Swatch" to work?